# Ubuntu unable to Connect to Internet at Work Network

Tags: 12.10, internet-connection

Hi I had been using Windows at my work Network and I recently asked the IT support to change my OS to ubuntu. They have installed the OS but I am not able to connect to the wired internet. The output of ipconfig/all is:

> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 01HW******
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : xxxx.xxx.com
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : xxxx.xxx.com
                                        xxxx.xxx.com
                                        xxx.com
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xx.x
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xx.xxx
    Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.xx.x
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 11, 2012 12:30:32PM
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 11, 2012 1:00:32 PM
```

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet-1:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter forVMnet1
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xx.x
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxxxx.xxx.com
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.xx.xxx
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.xx.x
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.xx.xx
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.xx.xx
                                        172.20.xx.x
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 11, 2012 4:00:38 AM
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 12, 2012 4:00:38 AM
```

Ethernet adapter Network Connect Adapter:

```
    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter-Teefer2 Miniport
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

I have replaced the numbers with 'x' for security purpose.

**How do I configure these details in Ubuntu? Especially the Primary DNS suffix? I believe if I do that I might be able to connect to the internet.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the network working by **installing cntlm and configuring it**.

You need to enter the password in cntlm. Setup your ubuntu proxy to the cntlm listen port. Then restart cntlm. You are set! You get networking for all your applications.